# How to use Ansible k8s module?

Tags: ansible, kubernetes

I am discovering Kubernetes and Ansible, and I am trying to build a very simple ansible playbook to initialize Kubernetes. I heard about a module "k8s" but I don't undertand how to use it.

For example the following task failed:

```
- name: "Add admin-user serviceAccount"
  k8s:
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: ServiceAccount
    metadata:
      name: admin-user
      namespace: kube-system
```

With the following error:

> Unsupported parameters for (k8s) module

ansible version: 2.7.5
os: Debian 4.9

**What should I do to use "k8s" module ?**
I also searched in ansible-galaxy but found nothing.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... I will answer my own question :D

[RTFM](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/k8s_module.html)

The YAML structure was wrong.